# Connect to SAP message server through JCo

Tags: java, sap-basis, jco

I have a working connection between my Java application and a SAP server through use of SAP JCo. The problem is that my connection is limited to 1 server.
There should be an option available for connecting to a SAP message server that acts like a load balancer.

Does anyone have an idea how this works?

My working Hibersap example:

`final SessionManagerConfig sessionManagerConfig = new SessionManagerConfig("");
sessionManagerConfig.setContext(JCoContext.class.getName());
sessionManagerConfig.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_ASHOST, "");
sessionManagerConfig.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_SYSNR, "");
sessionManagerConfig.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_CLIENT, "");
sessionManagerConfig.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_USER, "");
sessionManagerConfig.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_PASSWD, "");
sessionManagerConfig.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_LANG, "");

...`

Answer (score 7):

Instead of `JCO_ASHOST` and `JCO_SYSNR`, you have to provide

- `JCO_R3NAME` with the system ID of the target system
- `JCO_MSHOST` with the message server host name or address
- `JCO_MSSERV` with the message server port number
- `JCO_GROUP`  with the name of the logon group

See [this file](http://sourceforge.net/p/rcer/git/ci/master/tree/net.sf.rcer.conn/src/net/sf/rcer/conn/connections/ConnectionManager.java#l82) for a working example using JCo3.

Comment: Very nice example and it works now.
There are however several messages every time a request to SAP is made:
sapparam: sapargv(argc, argv) has not been called!
sapparam(14): FT_DLL (ref.by FN_DPLCOM) missing.
sapparam(14): FT_DLL (ref.by FN_JVM) missing.
sapparam(14): FT_DLL (ref.by FN_JVM) missing.
sapparam(14): FT_DLL (ref.by FN_LCOM) missing.
sapparam(14): FT_DLL (ref.by csi/SAP/csa_lib) missing.
sapparam(14): FT_DLL_SHR (ref.by igs/ip/zipper) missing.
...
sapparam(1c): No Profile used.
sapparam: SAPSYSTEMNAME neither in Profile nor in Commandline

Comment: If you provide JCO_MSSERV then JCO_R3NAME will be ignored. You do not have to set both of these properties. Furthermore JCO_MSSERV may also contain the symbolic service name like *sapmsABC* instead of the port number. But directly specifying the port number gives a tiny little bit better performance.